# Compiling C++ for Python using Swig

Tags: c++, python, g++, solaris, swig

I have successfully generated the .py and .cpp files needed using:

`swig -c++ -python sf_c_api.i`

but now I'm trying to make the shared object (.so) and I'm getting swamped with errors.

`g++ -Wall -g -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c atob.c fish.c maby_swap.c pwd_file.c pwd.c setup_fish.c shs.c sf_c_api.cpp sha1.cpp sf_c_api_wrap.cpp`

Can anyone make heads or tails of this g++ output?

```
In file included from /usr/include/python2.6/Python.h:8,
                 from sf_c_api_wrap.cpp:149:
/usr/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h:1038:1: warning: "_XOPEN_SOURCE" redefined
<built-in>: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/postypes.h:42,
                 from /usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/char_traits.h:42,
                 from /usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/string:42,
                 from /usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/stdexcept:39,
                 from sf_c_api_wrap.cpp:3024:
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:143: error: ‘::btowc’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:148: error: ‘::fwide’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:149: error: ‘::fwprintf’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:150: error: ‘::fwscanf’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:153: error: ‘::mbrlen’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:154: error: ‘::mbrtowc’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:155: error: ‘::mbsinit’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:156: error: ‘::mbsrtowcs’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:159: error: ‘::swprintf’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:160: error: ‘::swscanf’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:162: error: ‘::vfwprintf’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:166: error: ‘::vswprintf’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:170: error: ‘::vwprintf’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:174: error: ‘::wcrtomb’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:185: error: ‘::wcsrtombs’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:195: error: ‘::wctob’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:196: error: ‘::wmemcmp’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:197: error: ‘::wmemcpy’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:198: error: ‘::wmemmove’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:199: error: ‘::wmemset’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:200: error: ‘::wprintf’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:201: error: ‘::wscanf’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:205: error: ‘::wcsstr’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:206: error: ‘::wmemchr’ has not been declared
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar: In function ‘wchar_t* std::wcsstr(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)’:
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:223: error: invalid conversion from ‘const wchar_t*’ to ‘wchar_t*’
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:223: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘wchar_t* std::wcsstr(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*)’
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar: In function ‘wchar_t* std::wmemchr(wchar_t*, wchar_t, size_t)’:
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:227: error: invalid conversion from ‘const wchar_t*’ to ‘wchar_t*’
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/cwchar:227: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘wchar_t* std::wmemchr(wchar_t*, wchar_t, size_t)’
In file included from /usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/string:42,
                 from /usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/stdexcept:39,
                 from sf_c_api_wrap.cpp:3024:
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/char_traits.h: In static member function ‘static int std::char_traits<wchar_t>::compare(const wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, size_t)’:
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/char_traits.h:330: error: ‘wmemcmp’ was not declared in this scope/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/char_traits.h: In static member function ‘static const wchar_t* std::char_traits<wchar_t>::find(const wchar_t*, size_t, const wchar_t&)’:
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/char_traits.h:338: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘wchar_t* std::wmemchr(wchar_t*, wchar_t, size_t)’
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/char_traits.h: In static member function ‘static wchar_t* std::char_traits<wchar_t>::move(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, size_t)’:
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/char_traits.h:342: error: ‘wmemmove’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/char_traits.h: In static member function ‘static wchar_t* std::char_traits<wchar_t>::copy(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, size_t)’:
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/char_traits.h:346: error: ‘wmemcpy’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/char_traits.h: In static member function ‘static wchar_t* std::char_traits<wchar_t>::assign(wchar_t*, size_t, wchar_t)’:
/usr/gcc/4.4/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.4.4/../../../../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/char_traits.h:350: error: ‘wmemset’ was not declared in this scope

/../include/c++/4.4.4/bits/char_traits.h:338: error: invalid conversion from ‘const wchar_t*’ to ‘wchar_t*’
```

Comment: No one can make heads or tails out of SWIG's compiler output.

Comment: @Awalias: My WAG: Try adding `#include <wchar.h>` to your sf_c_api.i.

Comment: @Awalias: If my above advice fails to fix it, have g++ produce preprocessed source file using the `-save-temps` flag. It should be named `sf_c_api_wrap.ii`. Inspect that to see how, if at all, are all the wchar_t routines declared.

Comment: @wilx including it didn't seem to work. in the .ii I can find a few instances: `extern int mbtowc(wchar_t *, const char *, size_t);`, `extern int fwprintf(__FILE *, const wchar_t *`, and then `using ::fwprintf;` etc...

Comment: Looks to me like your .i file is missing some #includes.  Show the .i file?

Comment: @MarkTolonen I've now included .i in question body

Comment: Start smaller. `%include` *one* file and try to get that to compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution.

The problem is that under solaris:

> If `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED=1`, g++ cannot compile even an empty body
>   that `#includes <iostream>`.  If it's undefined, then gcc cannot compile
>   C code.

[[source]](http://lists.randombit.net/pipermail/botan-devel/2008-December/000707.html)

and from `/usr/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h`:

```
/* Define to activate Unix95-and-earlier features */
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1
```

Removing the XOPEN definitions fixed my problem.